# Radio group onclick event not firing, how do I tell which is selected?

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm using radio group but `RadioGroup` `onClick` event is not firing and 
the method `getCheckedRadiobuttonID()` is returning `null`. Here is the element in my **layout:**

```
   <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RG1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:onClick="onRGClick" >
```

**Method**

```
public void onRGClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Test ", 1000).show();
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This problem can be solved using the following

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                switch(checkedId)
                {
                case R.id.radio0:
                    // TODO Something
                    break;
                case R.id.radio1:
                    // TODO Something
                    break;
                case R.id.radio2:
                    // TODO Something
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

#### Alternatively

You can use custom ids rather than default one

```
  RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
                {
                    switch(checkedId)
                    {
                    case R.id.male:
                        // TODO Something
                        break;
                    case R.id.female:
                        // TODO Something
                        break;
                    case R.id.other:
                        // TODO Something
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I was confused about this at first: The code in this answer needs to be in `OnCreate` or `OnCreateView` (but correct me if I'm wrong), I tried to just put it in my activity class initially

Answer (score 7):

Actually I think you do not need to add `android:clickable="true"` or click listener. You can declare `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` which will listen for change of the selection. Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780981/android-radio-group-question) for example how you can use that.

Comment: where need to add android:clickable="true" ?

Comment: @Sametöztoprak nowhere, as I have written you do not need this attribute

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : I did some *changes* in your code and its working for me. onClick works for all the views. Here in your code, Rgroup's width is wrap_content, so if you have put RadioButtons inside the RG (which will completely overlap the RG), your clicks would be consumed by the RadioButtons (and not the Rgroup). I made the Rgroup's width to fill_parent and the click was getting executed. Here is my sample so that you can try it out.

```
    <RadioGroup  android:onClick="onRGClick" ndroid:text="RadioButton" 
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton android:text="RadioButton" android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
```

And here is the Activity:

```
public class Hello extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     }
    public void onRGClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Test ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Just click anywhere to the right of the RadioButton, and you will see the Toast. 
Although for general purposes,`OnCheckedChangeListener` is more useful.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Have you check first check and then answer it isn't working
Call event for radiobutton works well but the call event for radiogroup is not working

Comment: I first changed your code and then made it work.Should have written the first line properly, sorry about that. did u try the code given in my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The other way is to assign your method to `onClick` property of each `RadioButton`. Then check for the view id. For instance,

```
public void onRGClick(View v) {
    int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.radioButtonId) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```