# Call method on click of any RadioButton in a RadioGroup Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've got a RadioGroup of RadioButtons. When each button is selected, it autofills an EditText with some preset text. The method for doing this is the same for each button, though it depends what the sender is. Right now, my code for doing this is:

```
rb1.Click += RadioButtonClicked;
rb2.Click += RadioButtonClicked;
rb3.Click += RadioButtonClicked;
```

However, I was wondering if there's any way I can consolidate this. I only have 3 buttons right now, but if I had 20 buttons it would be very dirty to ave 20 lines of code assigning the same method to each button

Comment: you question is not clear .What you wants ? what is the problem ?

Comment: is this xamarin forms?

Comment: I'm using C#, but not Xamarin forms. And I edited it a bit to make it clearer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780981/android-radiogroup-how-to-configure-the-event-listener